# MAMP SQL. После обновления до Win10 не работает Apache

Tags: c#, sql, mamp

Apache загорается на 1 секунду и гаснет.

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED выдает браузер . HELP[image: ![Локальный сервер подключается на 1 сек и сразу гаснет]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0q6C.png)

ЛОГИ c запуска после обновления:

```
[Thu Feb 13 16:51:32 2020] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Thu Feb 13 16:51:33 2020] [warn] pid file C:/MAMP/bin/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Thu Feb 13 16:51:33 2020] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Feb 13 16:51:33 2020] [notice] Digest: done
[Thu Feb 13 18:02:32 2020] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Thu Feb 13 18:02:33 2020] [warn] pid file C:/MAMP/bin/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Thu Feb 13 18:02:33 2020] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Feb 13 18:02:33 2020] [notice] Digest: done
[Thu Feb 13 18:02:50 2020] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Thu Feb 13 18:02:51 2020] [warn] pid file C:/MAMP/bin/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
```

Comment: С такими исходными данными вопрос надо на битве экстрасенсов задавать.

Comment: Скажите что нужно добавить, добавлю.

Comment: Например, что за mamp, как его запускаете, как он позволяет Вам что то видеть в браузере, наличие процесса этой штуки в системе, настройки брандмауэра, адрес, по которому она должна быть доступна, ее логи при запуске, что там есть в эвентлоге в системе и как это все связано с c#

Comment: Все не так сложно было ) . Скачивал MySQL Connector, устанавливал, указывал ddl-ку в ссылках. Затем запускал MAMP оттуда на PHPMyAdmin с моим локальным сервером и моими базами данных. Все работало в программе до тех пор, пока не обновил до Win10. Брандмауэр выключил не помогло.

Comment: MAMP это для создания локального сервера .

Comment: Про брандмауэр понял, что насчет остальных вопросов?

Comment: Переустановить пробовали эту штуку?

Comment: Логов в этой проге нет. НО! Все это время я копал и проблема скорее всего в том что, что не запускается локальный сервер. Он запускается на секунду и сразу гаснет. Да я все переустановил. И Connector и mamp

Comment: Логи должны быть где то. Либо где то в файлах, либо в эвентлоге винды. Сервер тоже должен писать куда то причину, чего он гаснет.

Comment: Вы правы я их нашел.

Comment: Что то гуглится похожее https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54296014/mysql-server-on-mamp-windows-will-not-start

Comment: Ну или вот https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46868318/mamp-wont-start-apache-windows-10

Comment: Короче я хз что такое mamp, но вы походу не первый с такой проблемой, вот еще ссылка https://superuser.com/questions/1485892/apache-not-starting-in-mamp-but-mysql-working-in-windows-10

Comment: Там и рестарт советуют, и версию пхп поменять, пробуйте

Comment: PHP менял. На логах примерно понятно в какое русло смотреть а именно ""Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?"". Вот из за этой ошибки не запускает.

Comment: Это ошибка скорее всего говорит просто о том, что предыдущий запуск был неудачный

Comment: В общем проблема осталась нерешённой. Да и своей базы данных я уже не вижу там...

Comment: У вас сервер бд не запускается или вашей бд на сервере не видно?

Comment: бд была на сервере ,но после переустановки конектора (или чего другого) пропала. Я просто скачал XAMP и через него зашло.